# How can I reverse this linked list starting from nth element to the end

Tags: java, algorithm

So I'm trying to construct a method in Java that when called will take as the parameter how many elements at the end of the `LinkedList` will be reversed.

So, if I have

```
{hat cat bat mat}
```

and I input 2 as my parameters, then the last 2 elements will be reversed like this

```
{hat cat mat bat}
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
public void reverseLastFew(int howMany)
   {
       int s = size();
       LinkedListIterator iter1 = new LinkedListIterator();
       LinkedListIterator iter2 = new LinkedListIterator();
       for (int i=0;i<s-howMany;i++)
       {
           iter1.next();
       }
       for (int i = 0;i<s;i++)
       {
           iter2.next();
       }
       Object temp = null;
       while (iter2.hasNext())
       {
           temp = iter2.next();
       }
       iter2.remove();
       iter1.add(temp);

   }
```

Comment: Do you need a java code or an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution to a similar question:

```
Reverse a linked list from position m to n. Do it in-place and in one-pass.

For example:
Given "1"->"2"->"3"->"4"->"5"->NULL, m = 2 and n = 4,

return "1"->"4"->"3"->"2"->"5"->NULL.
```

Solution:

```
 /**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     String val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(String x) {
 *         val = x;
 *         next = null;
 *     }
 * }
 */
public class Solution {
    public ListNode reverseBetween(ListNode head, int m, int n) {
        if (head==null) {
            return null;
        }

        ListNode dummy = new ListNode(" ");
        dummy.next = head;
        head = dummy;

        for (int i=1; i<m; i++) {
            head = head.next;
        }

        ListNode pre = head;
        ListNode start = head.next;
        ListNode end = start;
        ListNode post = start.next;

        for (int i=m; i<n; i++) {
            if (post==null) {
                return null;
            }

            ListNode temp = post.next;
            post.next = end;
            end = post;
            post = temp;
        }

        start.next = post;
        pre.next = end;

        return dummy.next;
    }
}
```

So, you can calculate `m` and `n` with what you have, or modify this solution to solve your question directly. Anyway, this in-place and one-pass solution is really nice.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code..........

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class LinkListTry {
public LinkedList<String> linkedlist;

public LinkListTry(){
    linkedlist = new LinkedList<String>();
}

public void insertElement(String element){
    linkedlist.add(element);
}

public void printListElement(){
    System.out.println(linkedlist);
}

public void reverseLastFewElement(int howmany){
    LinkedList<String> temp = new LinkedList<String>();
    while(howmany > 0){
        String str = linkedlist.removeLast();
        temp.add(str);
        --howmany;
    }
    linkedlist.addAll(temp);
}
}



public class LinkedListTryMain {
public static void main(String[] args){
    LinkListTry test = new LinkListTry();
    test.insertElement("hat");
    test.insertElement("cat");
    test.insertElement("bat");
    test.insertElement("mat");

    test.printListElement();
    test.reverseLastFewElement(2);
    test.printListElement();
}
}
```